# Blazor - Bool never gets set in OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, .net-7.0, blazor-hybrid

Still very new to Blazor and working on a NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app. Wondering why in the code example hideDiv never gets set to false in OnAfterRenderAsync? Code example below:

```
    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1">@hideDiv</MudText>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" Class="@(hideDiv ? "invisible" : "")">
     ...
    </MudItem>


@code{

        private bool hideDiv { get; set; } = true;
    
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("twttr.widgets.load");
                hideDiv = false;
            }
         }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call the `StateHasChanged();` after you set the `hideDiv = false;`. Such as:

```
if (firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("twttr.widgets.load");
    hideDiv = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: Zhnag Thanks added StateHasChanged() and working now! I will have to read up on using that. Thanks again!

Comment: Be aware, you rarely need to call `StateHasChanged` [unless you have your logic wrong].  This is one occasion where you do.   `OnAfterRender` is a UI event, not part of the component lifecycle.  As such, the component's lifecycle may have already completed when it's executed .  You're changing the state of the component so you need to do another render cycle by calling `StateHasChanged` for the change to be reflected in the rendered content.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks for the additional clarification! I will have read up on component lifecycle, but this is handy information.  Somebody else mentioned that "if you are in an async method then I would suggest you use await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);" Thoughts? Would that be better pattern than simply calling StateHasChanged();?

Comment: You use `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` when the method containing it is run on a different thread outside the synchronisation context.  That will normally be on an event handler.  I wouldn't always use it,  When you code it wrong you'll soon find out, and learn where to and not to use it.